# Google AppEngine DataStore Read & Write (Golang)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using the http package to create a simple Golang server to pass in some query string parameters in the /add directory. The app would then 
1.) parse the query string parameters, 
2.) put them into a struct and 
3.) write them to the datastore.

This appears to work fine...

However, when I then try to make a query to search for "Bob" "Smith" when I enter that in the struct, it returns no members, as evidenced by running:
len(storeVals)
and getting 0 as a result.

I was hoping somebody would be familiar enough with Google's AppEngine DataStore to help me out.

Many thanks!

edit: I have looked at the similar question: [Google App Engine Datastore - Testing Queries fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28590519/google-app-engine-datastore-testing-queries-fails) and have revised my code below. Even when first performing the write, and then later (10s) performing the read, I still get no returning members!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "net/url"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"
)

type storeVal struct {
    firsN   string
    lastN   string
    Date    time.Time
}

func write(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    m, _ := url.ParseQuery(r.URL.RawQuery)

    e1 := storeVal{
        firstN:     m["firstN"][0],
        lastN:      m["lastN"][0],
        Date:       time.Now(),
    }

    key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "storeVal", nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &e1)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func read(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    m, _ := url.ParseQuery(r.URL.RawQuery)

    q := datastore.NewQuery("storeVal").
        Filter("firstN =", m["firstN"][0]).
        Filter("lastN =", m["lastN"][0]).
        Order("-Date")
    var storeVals []storeVal
    _, err := q.GetAll(c, &storeVals)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "--%d--", len(storeVals))  //Always returns --0--!!
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", read)
    http.HandleFunc("/add", write)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: You'll need a custom index for that query - have you defined one?

Comment: @tx802
Hmmm. Not explicitly. my index.yaml looks like this:
`indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED

- kind: storeVal
  properties:
  - name: firstN
  - name: lastN
  - name: Date
    direction: desc`